# Cosa significa "è tutto un programma" in questa frase?

Tags: meaning, idioms

In un esercizio di italiano ho trovato la frase seguente:

> Altro che commedia. Il titolo del film la dice lunga, **è tutto un programma**!

Ho un dubbio sul significato dell'espressione "essere tutto un programma" in questa frase.

Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/programma/), *essere tutto un programma* significa

> nel linguaggio colloquiale, essere particolarmente indicativo di ciò che accadrà o di come si svolgeranno i fatti, avere in sé indizî tali da lasciar presumere gli avvenimenti futuri (*il suo atteggiamento è tutto un p.; mi ha fatto un discorso ch’era tutto un programma*).

La definizione del dizionario De Mauro è simile. Basandomi su questo, ho pensato che il significato della frase fosse che il titolo del film permette di immaginare ciò che accadrà nella pellicola.

Tuttavia, nel [Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/P/programma.shtml) ho trovato una spiegazione diversa:

> **essere tutto un programma (*fam*)** 
>      • Fig.: si dice di qualcosa che s'impone per la sua singolarità, per caratteristiche tanto originali e curiose da apparire buffe o da sfiorare il ridicolo. Per estensione, all'opposto, essere qualcosa di problematico, difficile, faticoso, cui tuttavia ci si rassegna.

Questo mi ha fatto pensare ad altri possibili significati della frase: il titolo del film è tanto singolare che pare buffo, ridicolo, o magari fa prevedere un film faticoso o noioso.

Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il senso della frase sopra citata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il [nuovo De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/tutto-un-programma) definisce l'espressione come:

> che è particolarmente significativo, che costituisce una chiara
>   indicazione di ciò che una persona è o farà o di come si svolgeranno i
>   fatti: il suo comportamento è tutto un programma

Nel tuo caso, riferito al film, questo significato può essere calzante.
Il significato adatto al tuo contesto è che puoi immaginare dal già dal titolo ciò che ti aspetta. Poi a seconda dei tuoi gusti può essere piacevole o spiacevole.

Ad esempio, se il film fosse Cimitero vivente (Pet Sematary) allora potresti certamente dire: "Altro che commedia. Il titolo del film la dice lunga, è tutto un programma!"

In effetti però ***è tutto un programma*** l'ho già sentito anche usare con accezione figurata e parzialmente negativa, cioè, come dice Hoepli, so già cosa mia aspetta e purtroppo sarà spiacevole e difficoltoso.

Ad esempio:

> Oggi devo lavorare con lui e la giornata sarà tutta un programma!!

nel senso di avere a che fare con un collega difficile e con cui non si lavora agevolmente.

Comment: Quindi, il significato è che il titolo del film permette di immaginare ciò che accadrà e che questo sarà spiacevole e dificoltoso?

Comment: Secondo me il significato principale relativo al tuo contesto è che puoi immaginare dal titolo ciò che ti aspetta. Poi a seconda dei tuoi gusti può essere piacevole o spiacevole. Ad esempio, se il film fosse Cimitero vivente (Pet Sematary) allora potresti certamente dire: "Altro che commedia. Il titolo del film la dice lunga, è tutto un programma!"

Answer (score 0):

La definizione del vocabolario Treccani è secondo me maggiormente corretta, ma, almeno nella mia esperienza, questa espressione assume spesso un significato almeno ironico (o addirittura sarcastico), e questo spiega la definizione che dà il dizionario Hoepli.

Credo che nella frase indicata, significhi che il titolo del film lascia trasparire le sue vere intenzioni (che non sono quelle di essere una commedia).

Mi vengono in mente espressioni in inglese (ma non identiche in significato) come *that says it all* o *'nuff said*.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for replying in English but I don't want to risk writing incorrect Italian.)

`Essere tutto un / tutta una [something]` has a similar meaning to `Being a whole [something]` or `Being a [something] in itself`, it's sort of a common western European idiom. It means the thing being discussed can assume the qualities of the thing it's being compared to, which wouldn't normally be expected of something of its kind.

In this specific case, I think there are two different meanings:

- The title is the whole show / a whole [guide to the] show: the title gives away the plot. This is the idiom used with a neutral sense of `programma`.
- abarisone's The day will be fully a spectacle / a full-on spectacle / nothing less of a spectacle: working with such a person will be a demanding experience of the kind one finds in fiction, not normal real life. This is the very same idiom, but with a figurative sense of `programma`.

In short, I don't think the difference lies in the `è tutto un` idiom itself but in the sense used for `programma`. If that's correct, then it's not a matter of the same expression covering a complex range of meaning, but rather of one of its components (`programma`) having two distinct meanings, in accordance with which the meaning of the whole will also change.

Answer (score 0):

Penso che la definizione contenuta nel Dizionario Hoepli sia quella che più si avvicina alla realtà. 
Non è un'espressione che uso spesso, ma quando lo faccio è perché voglio fare del sarcasmo di proposito.

Altri contesti in cui l'ho sentita usare, negli anni:

"Ma hai visto come va in giro? Cappotto blu, calze rosse, cappello fucsia... ***tutto un programma***" (= il suo aspetto è ridicolo)